# Material ui - change the height of the Accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on the migration of a JavaFx HMI to a web application working with React.js. For the display of graphical widgets, I'm also working with Material.ui.

To match with the layout of the HMI I have to update the layout of some predefined components by Material ui.

In my case, I need to reduce the height of the Accordion.
I did something like this :

```
const IconLeftAccordionSummary = withStyles({
  root: {
    minHeight: 15,
    maxHeight: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#a5a5a5',
})(AccordionSummary);
```

and then I basically use it like this

```
<IconLeftAccordionSummary>
</IconLeftAccordionSummary>
```

Here is the result, it's what I'm expected when it's collapsed.
[image]

However, when I expand it, it comes back to its original height, with some margins between blocks.
Like this:
[image]

I tried different things like adding

```
'&$expanded': {
  minHeight: 15,
  maxHeight: 15,
},
```

or

```
expanded: {
  minHeight: 15,
  maxHeight: 15
},
```

in the definition of IconLeftAccordionSummary, but nothing changes.

Does anyone can help me on how to do this ? Am I at least trying to do it in the right way?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some tries I found an answer:

```
const StyledAccordionSummary = withStyles({
root: {
    minHeight: 15,
    maxHeight: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#a5a5a5',
    '&.Mui-expanded': {
      minHeight: 15,
      maxHeight: 15,
      backgroundColor: '#a5a5a5',
    }
},
expandIcon: {
    order: -1
}
})(AccordionSummary);
```

And I apply this style to the AccordionSummary component.

"root" applies on the accordion when it's closed, and the '&.Mui-expanded' applies on the accordion when it's opened.

Comment: Both this solution and the one below rely on the deprecated mui/styles API. Would be great to see an example using the new mui/system API.

Answer (score 2):

It's just necessary to override Accordion's `root` on `classes` prop. Something like:

```
<Accordion classes={{ root: classes.accordionRoot }}>
...
</Accordion>
```

And then in your `makeStyles`:

```
accordionRoot: {
   height: "15px"
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-accordion-menu-forked-t725z?file=/src/App.tsx) a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) Indeed it worked, but this leads me to 2 unexpected behaviour.
I was expecting the "expand icon" and the text "main title" to be within the rectangle, and not below (as it was beforce the reduction of the size).
Furthermore, if I add another Accordion, when expanded, it's displayed under the 1st one, not below (cf https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-accordion-menu-forked-dulkr?file=/src/App.tsx) is this a normal behavior ? Just by changing the height I can get the expected result

Comment: @Ptiseb yes I see that height affects only Accordion (and not summary...). I read [this](https://smartdevpreneur.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-styling-and-customizing-material-ui-accordion/) and the conclusion is "I don’t recommend changing height." =). If you still want to change height I think you should also override AccordionSummary and AccordionDetails. As an alternative I propose you [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-accordion-menu-forked-rncwo?file=/src/App.tsx): Accordions on the same line (but maybe is not what you are looking for).

Comment: Thanks & sorry for the late reply, i had some other stuff to work on & I tested some things on this.
I could find a solution, but I don't like it. I directly updated the AccordionSummary.js file to replace 'minHeight: 64' in '&$expanded' by 'minHeight: 15, maxHeight: 15', and this works as expected for 2 Accordions.
What I don't get is why the solution I tried in my initial post didn't work, when I overrode '&$expanded' in IconLeftAccordionSummary..